# C#, WinCE Listview : opening a form when list view item is clicked

Tags: c#, listview, windows-ce, listviewitem

I just want to ask what is the best way to open a new form when a list view item is clicked?
Right now, I'm just using ShowDialog().

Thanks! :)

Comment: That is definitely a correct way to show a new form.  What exactly are you looking to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WinCE, using `ShowDialog` is the best way to open a new form, since the call's modal nature means the stacking of forms (z-order) is handled for you.  You could use `Show`, but then you have to manage your forms (i.e. which one is on top) yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks. It's just when I do ShowDialog() it is kind of slow to just initialize the components/controls on my new form. Now I'm guessing it's probably a slower device (MC9090-G) or I have too much control on my form.. but thanks anyway.. :)

Comment: @Jeff: if your initialization of controls is in the form's constructor, then the instantiation of the form should take a lot longer than the ShowDialog call. If you create/add controls in the form's Load event, then I would expect the ShowDialog call to take much longer than the instantiation.  Either way, you're going to take a performance hit - it won't matter how you're specifically showing the form (either with Show or ShowDialog).